# Why are time() and Date.now giving different results?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time

I am almost certain my previous function worked like a charm before but fails now. Maybe someone can help me? I have the following sample HTML code:

```
<span id="timetest" data-starttime="<?php echo time(); ?>"><?php echo time(); ?></span>
```

And then in Jquery I try to get the difference between the time() and the date.now() / 1000 (because of milliseconds) like this:

```
var startttime = $('#timetest').data('starttime');
var submitttime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
var totalttime = submitttime - startttime;
```

But whatever I do the outcome of totaltime = -66 (seconds) ish. What has changed, or what am I doing wrong? Anyone else noticed this issue?

Comment: Not every computer system in the world necessarily has its clock set absolutely correct … If server and client are different machines, there can easily be differences.

Comment: This is a good question, I tested Server/Browser on the same machine, it gives -1s, 0s randomly. If I d'ont round with Math.floor(), it can be also positive.

Answer (score 2):

Like CBroe said above: "Not every computer system in the world necessarily has its clock set absolutely correct … If server and client are different machines, there can easily be differences"